# Rails properly pass ID through loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Attempting to pass id's from my rails front end to back end.  I have the following bit of code in my Rails controller:

```
def count_vote
roster_id = params[:roster_id]
roster = Roster.find(roster_id)
newvote = roster.vote + 1
if roster.update({vote: newvote})
  redirect_to rosters_path
end
end
```

My rails view for roster has the following code:

```
<% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
  <div class='each'>
    <%= image_tag(roster['image_url'], class: 'image') %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:roster_id, @roster.id) %>
    <p class='name'> <%= roster['name'] %> </p>
    <p class='title'> <%= roster['title'] %> </p>
    <p> <%= roster['bio'] %> </p>
    <p> <b> Want to work with <%= roster['name'] %>? </b> <%= link_to image_tag('thumbs-up.svg', class: 'thumbsup'), rosters_path, method: :patch %>
    <br>
    <%= roster['vote'] %> People have said Yes! </p>
    <br>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to pass the ID using the hidden field tag but I get the following error in my rails server logs:

```
Started PATCH "/rosters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-09 17:43:56 -0500


(0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/sohel/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by RostersController#count_vote as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"DJAtI8yNTlP1kQK/g/6o9jbdqxWEBBgKinzLtf8v8WrDnYCmrH+HQI5wTEjJ0T6rkKbBz0KA/q2M0yirluozQg=="}
Completed 404 Not Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Roster without an ID):

app/controllers/rosters_controller.rb:22:in `count_vote'
```

Searching Roster.all in my error console returns the following, for brevity sake I will return only the first two:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Roster id: 1, name: "John Smith", image_url: "https://d2eyrv63e6x6lp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/u...", title: "CTO / Co-founder", bio: "John has been programming since his dad bought him...", vote: 3, created_at: "2018-11-09 02:46:39", updated_at: "2018-11-09 02:46:39">, #<Roster id: 2, name: "Michael Thomas", image_url: "https://d2eyrv63e6x6lp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/u...", title: "Senior Software Engineer", bio: "Michael has been working as a back-end developer sin...", vote: 3, created_at: "2018-11-09 02:46:39", updated_at: "2018-11-09 02:46:39">
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= hidden_field_tag('roster[id]', roster.id) %>`?

Comment: Yes, still getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

```
hidden_field_tag(:roster_id, @roster.id)
```

should be

```
hidden_field_tag(:roster_id, roster.id)
```

Because there is no defined instance variable `@roster`

Also try to change this line to

`<p> <b> Want to work with <%= roster['name'] %>? </b> <%= link_to image_tag('thumbs-up.svg', class: 'thumbsup'), rosters_path(roster), method: :patch %`

Comment: The error I get with the hidden_field change is 'undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x00007fc711750488>'

Comment: It won't read the params[:roster_id] in my controller, returns nil.  Roster.find(1) however returns the different people by id number

Comment: check to make sure `params.permit` allows the param you're passing in your controller